# Assessing video card performance for canvas rendering in firemonkey

Tags: c++, directx, firemonkey, c++builder-xe8

Recently, my team began noticing issues with our current C++ builder project running strangely on different computers.  We have narrowed this down to the fact that we are running the application with `GlobalUseGPUCanvas` set to `true`.  As far as my understanding goes, this means that firemonkey will use the GPU to render the canvas.  We noticed that the machines having trouble, were those with less powerful integrated graphics cards.  Therefore, I am looking to write some logic which will only enable `GlobalUseGPUCanvas` is the user has a powerful enough graphics card.

To start this, I have written the following code which I based heavily on [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476877(v=vs.85).aspx).  This allows me to loop through all of the video cards on the machine and see how much memory they have.

```
    IDXGIFactory * pFactory = NULL;
    CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory) ,(void**)&pFactory);

    IDXGIAdapter * pAdapter;
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC * adapterDesc;

    for (UINT i = 0; pFactory->EnumAdapters(i, &pAdapter) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND; ++i)
    {
         pAdapter->GetDesc(adapterDesc);

         long vidMemory = adapterDesc->DedicatedVideoMemory;

         long sMemory = adapterDesc->SharedSystemMemory;
    }

    if( pFactory )
    {
        pFactory->Release();
    }
```

This is a decent start, because I can check the computers video cards to see if they have enough memory to run the program on the video card.  However, I am not sure how to handle the scenario where a machine might have a really nice dedicated graphics card, but could have internal graphics enabled instead.  For example, I could see the powerful dedicated card and think they have enough memory, but if they were for some reason running off of less powerful integrated graphics, I might be mistaken.

Is there anyway to be able to tell which of these graphics cards I am enumerating through is the active graphics device?

Comment: How about having a just a manual setting in INI file for your application so if GlobalUseGPUCanvas = true doesnt work the user can set it different?

Comment: @DougRudd That is definitely a good idea, and something we have considered.  However, we wanted to make this happen behind the scenes without the user having to do anything, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your program on a machine that has an internal and a dedicated graphics card. `EnumAdapters` returns only the active graphics card.

If more than one adapter is active, for example because it is a multi monitor system, `EnumAdapters`might return more results. Then you have to decide, but [MSDN has a Hint for you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174538(v=vs.85).aspx):

> EnumAdapters first returns the adapter with the output on which the
>   desktop primary is displayed.